# Google / Youtube Api (v3) - verify the owner of a video

Tags: php, symfony, youtube-api

**Context:**
I'm building a website using Symfony2 (php) and I have already implemented a social(google) login function (through HWIOAuthBundle) that allows users to:
- register a new account using their own google account
- link a google account to an existing non-social account
As a result, in my database the `users` table already has a `google_id` field.

**What I want to do:**
Users must be able to submit youtube links of their own videos. These links will be saved in the database BUT first I need to verify that the video BELONGS(IS OWNED) to the user that is submitting the link. In other words: users CAN NOT submit videos uploaded by someone else.
I plan on using the Youtube API (php) that you can find on the google developers website.

**Question(s):**
How can I verify this condition? Can I use the Google Id that I already have in my `users` table? Or do I need to create a new `youtube_id` field because the id is different from the `google_id`? What api function/method should I call to verify the video ownership?
Ideas?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you need to do some more reading into the API usage before progressing any further. You will be able to find the info you need from the reference pages

Answer (score 1):

Try to check them by v3/videos  - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

if you use "part=snippet"
you will see channel info in items->snippet->channelId and items->snippet->channelTitle

For example for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVe2THgSDxc load

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YVe2THgSDxc&part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

You will get

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "*******",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "*******",
   "id": "YVe2THgSDxc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-01-22T15:47:46.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCiP6wD_tYlYLYh3agzbByWQ",
    "title": "30 Minute HIIT Cardio*******",
    "description": "Full info for thi*******.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YVe2THgSDxc/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
    *******
    },
    "channelTitle": "FitnessBlender",
    "tags": [
     "fitness blender",
     "fitness",
     "blender",
     "workout",
     "workout videos",
     "hiit workout",
     "cardio workout",
     "hiit cardio",
     "cardio at home",
     "hiit at home",
     "at home hiit",
     "at home workouts",
     "free workout videos",
     "hiit cardio workout",
     "strength",
     "strength training",
     "strength training workout",
     "dumbbell workout",
     "at home strength training",
     "strength and hiit",
     "hiit and strength",
     "lower body workout",
     "butt workout",
     "thigh workout",
     "butt and thigh workout",
     "fat burning workout",
     "muscle building workout"
    ],
    "categoryId": "26",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "30 Minute HIIT Ca*******",
     "description": "Full info for this *******"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

So if you have users's channelID or channelName you can compare it with video's channelID or channelName.

---

**If you have user's name but haven't his channel list** you can get it by  v3/channels

For example this gets channel list for user "popsugartvfit"

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?&part=contentDetails&forUsername=popsugartvfit&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

You will get

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "*****",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "*******",
   "id": "UCBINFWq52ShSgUFEoynfSwg",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UUBINFWq52ShSgUFEoynfSwg",
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And use if for validation